# The relationship implied in the "noun of noun" structure.

Tags: prepositions, possessives

> By a strange **quirk of fate** they had booked into the same hotel.
>
> an unpredictable **quirk of history**

Is the relationship between **quirk** and **fate/history** the same as that in the following examples:

> the result of the debate; a stroke of luck; a streak of cruelty

Sometimes I get confused by the relationship implied in the "noun of noun" structure.

Help me demystify it.

Comment: Intuitively, I think it could be easier to understand *of* as a word that is used to show some kind of relation or connection between the parts before and after it. As I understand, *of* has been taught to ELLs in the context of *'s* or possessives. If it's possible, try to extend that sense and make it more general to cover other senses of *of*.

Comment: That's also what I have always thought about, but I needed elaboration on how this mechanism works. @DamkerngT.

Comment: It would be great if I could explain all the rules that govern all the uses of all the words in English precisely, or in our case, prepositions, *of* in particular. Sadly, I know I cannot. (I wonder if anyone could do that!) However, here is my tip. My approach is, instead of working our way from a word to its uses, we could get a better picture of it if we do the opposite: start with how it's really used out there in the wild, to arrive at its meaning (or meanings if you'd like).

Answer (score 1):

Damkerng T. should have made his comment an answer as it seems like one good way to think about it.  Using his suggestion of possessive, and place for example, we have those royal titles such as the *Queen of England.*

But what about the more subtle ones similar to your examples?

Here's another way. Bear with me, it's a bit abstract at first. Let's take the structure apart. We have to think in a flexible way, a bit artistically for a minute.

Consider the second noun *like* a cause or an *actor*. The first noun is *like* a result or an *action*.

Given: ***noun1 of noun2.***

**Noun2** is usually the bigger, more encompassing concept: fate, history, luck, debate, or *place.*  Often, the bigger concept is [anthropomorphized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropomorphism), but typically not overtly. The second noun acts either passively or (subtly) actively.

**Noun1** is a part, a piece, or a process - the "result" of an "act" - out of that bigger concept.

**So one trick is to turn it around.**

> A turn of fate - becomes - fate has turned something in a different / unexpected / perhaps *deserved* direction.
>
> A quirk of history - becomes (loosely!) - history is quirky, it has "issued" something unexpected.

Notice above how many variations I had to bring in?  And there are more! Such sayings have poetic license, nuance, implications, and bring in wonder of the language.

> A draw of the cards - similar to a turn of fate, a stroke of luck. He has drawn a good (or bad) card.  Turning that one around is not needed because the actor in this instance is the card player who draws the cards. But it does have nuances to the others, e.g. stroke of luck, turn of history. Same goes for *"a roll of the dice."*

Consider this:

> Luck of the draw.

Again a possible reference to drawing cards, but we also 'draw lots' or 'draw straws' to achieve the same result of random selection like flipping a coin.

Many forms are also idiomatic. Every language has their own unique versions and may be the forerunners of parallel versions in other languages. Some of ours for instance have roots in the German, etc.

Here are some idiomatic sayings - I don't know what they all mean! Perhaps someone else could comment in?  (Implying too that you shouldn't feel bad if you can't figure out what they mean. You can always ask here.)

> Hair of the dog.
>
> Eye of the tiger.

Probably not at all similar to:

> Eye of the storm = the storm's 'eye,' the calm center of a hurricane.

And, last but not least:

> Fruit of the Loom

:))